# Insert table into a word document at a specific position using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I am working on a project where I am trying to create an automated report generator. I need to pinpoint a couple of specific paragraphs, eliminate the tables that are already there and insert a new table.

Everything up to this point works perfect. I even manage to insert a sample text in the place that I want, but... all the tables are placed at the end of the document, despite what I do.

```
public class InsertText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
            InvalidFormatException {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\Work\\current\\***.docx");
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
            fis.close();
            System.out.println(document.getDocument().getBody().getPArray().length);
            List<IBodyElement> elements = document.getBodyElements();
            for (int n = 0; n < elements.size(); n++) {
                IBodyElement element = elements.get(n);
                if (element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                    XWPFParagraph p1 = (XWPFParagraph) element;
                    List<XWPFRun> runList = p1.getRuns();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (XWPFRun run : runList)
                        sb.append(run.getText(0));
                    if (sb.toString().contains("????")) {
                        n++;
                        element = elements.get(n);
                        if (element instanceof XWPFTable) {
                            XWPFTable t = (XWPFTable) element;
                            XmlCursor cursor = t.getCTTbl().newCursor();
                            document.removeBodyElement(n);
                            XWPFParagraph p = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
                            XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
                            run.setText("GOAL!!!");
                            XWPFTable t2 = document.createTable(3,4);
                            XWPFTableCell cell = t2.getRow(0).getCell(0);
                            document.insertTable(n, t2);
                            cell.setText("GOAL!!!");
                            t2 = p.getBody().insertNewTbl(cursor);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Work/Current/**.docx");
            document.write(outStream);
            outStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you can't use one cursor for multiple purposes, so all I needed to do was to create a fresh cursor for my future table.

```
run.setText("GOAL!!!");
cursor = p.getCTP().newCursor();//this is the key!
XWPFTable t2 = document.insertNewTbl(cursor);
XWPFTableCell cell = t2.getRow(0).getCell(0);
cell.setText("GOAL!!!");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
//first row
XWPFTableRow  rowOfOriginalTable  = theOriginalTable.getRow(0); 

//second cell of the first row
XWPFTableCell cellOfOriginalTable = rowOfOriginalTable.getCell(1);

//new paragraph in that cell
XWPFParagraph p = cellOfOriginalTable.addParagraph();

//get the cursor of the new paragraph
XmlCursor cursor = p.getCTP().newCursor();

//add the nested Table
XWPFTable nestedTable = p.getBody().insertNewTbl(cursor);

//add the first row to the nested table
XWPFTableRow rowOfNestedTable = nestedTable.createRow();

//add a cell to the first row
XWPFTableCell cellOfNestedTable = rowOfNestedTable.createCell();

//add a value
cellOfNestedTable.setText("Cell 0,0");

//add another cell
cellOfNestedTable = rowOfNestedTable.createCell();
cellOfNestedTable.setText("Cell 0,1");


//add another cell and rows
rowOfNestedTable = nestedTable.createRow();
cellOfNestedTable = rowOfNestedTable.getCell(0);
cellOfNestedTable.setText("Cell 1,0");

cellOfNestedTable = rowOfNestedTable.getCell(1);
cellOfNestedTable.setText("Cell 1,1");

cellOfOriginalTable.addParagraph();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will insert a table at a given position:

```
CTTbl inserted = doc.getDocument().getBody().insertNewTbl(position);    
XWPFTable newTable = new XWPFTable(inserted, doc);
```

Where `doc` is an XWPFDocument object and `position` is your position among other tables.